# How to use datatables in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I want to try pagination using datatables.net via ajax.

I have 2 input fields which sends start date and end date and following is the table structure

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="example">
              <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Loan ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Loan Amount</th>
            <th>Loan Type</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="amount"></tbody></table>
```

when the button is clicked,I am calling this function

```
$('#recv').click(function(){
      var fromDate=$('#from').val();
      var toDate=$('#to').val();

      var test=$.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
           url: "/project/getDetails",  
              data:{"fromDate":fromDate,"toDate":toDate},
              dataType:"json",async:false 
      }).responseText;
      var result = eval('('+test+')');
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": result,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "Loan_ID",
                                "bSearchable": false,
                                "bSortable": false

                            },
                            { "sName": "Date" },
                            { "sName": "Loan_Amount" },
                            { "sName": "Loan_Type" }
                        ]
        } );
```

When Ever I click on the button then I get error in alert box saying *datatables warning id=example ajax error*

Can anybody please tell me how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Let datatables take care of the ajax call:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "iDeferLoading": 1,
    "sAjaxSource": "/project/getDetails",
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "fromDate", "value": $('#from').val() });
        aoData.push({ "name": "toDate", "value": $('#to').val() });
        },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                  { "sName": "Loan_ID",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "bSortable": false
                  },
                { "sName": "Date" },
                { "sName": "Loan_Amount" },
                { "sName": "Loan_Type" }
              ]
        } );

$('#recv').click(function(){
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

Points to note:

- `fnServerParams`  this passes your start & end date to the 
  `getDetails` function
- `iDeferLoading` - prevent table population on    page load
- `fnDraw()`  populates the datatable from your click event

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives me error.When the page is loaded then also it gives me error,says ajax error

Comment: Have you removed or commented out your original code?

Comment: what is the js error? any reason you're not using `$(document).ready(function()`?

Comment: The error is *datatables warning:table id=example-ajax error.for more information about this error,please see http://datatables.net/tn/7*

Comment: well that's related to the url you're using for the ajax call - you probably need to use the full path `http://mysite/project/getDetails`

Comment: There is no need to 'uninitialize'. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are 2 tables in my page so I want to uninitialize one before another table is displayed.So I want to uninitialize becase both the tables are showing

Comment: How does this relate to your original question?

Comment: This is not related with my original question in any way ,I just needed one help.Also I tried another way like this http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html